# Highcharts datetime axis, how to disable time part (show only dates)?

Tags: javascript, datetime, highcharts

My chart is displaying data **day-by-day** (user and system sent SMS/Newsletters). So time part is not relevant and unnecessary. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/uaxZP/1/ where time "12:00" is displayed.

How can I force Highcharts to **never display the time part in a "datetime" axis**?

**EDIT**: Highcharts will display dates w/wo times based on chart or screen size. I've updated jsfiddle removing some data and now it's displaying also time parts.

Comment: Is this still a problem? I see only dates on your fiddle.

Comment: i would think about using highstock since you have your data in this format

Comment: @MikeRobinson here we are, updated fiddle showing times.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can intercept the x-axis label function and change it's output. In my example, I've changed it to render short dates:

http://jsfiddle.net/uaxZP/3/

```
{ xAxis: 
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
             return Highcharts.dateFormat("%b %e", this.value);
        }
    }
}
```

The xAxis.labels.formatter property allows control over this. You also may notice I'm using Highcharts.dateFormat, which is a utility function for rendering dates. This is not mandatory, but it's a nice built in feature. Documentation on the xAxis formatter is here:

http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#xAxis-labels--formatter

Comment: Actually right now i've found "tickInterval" option on Highcharts documentation. Seems to do the same thing when setted to 86400000 (1 day). What's the right choice?

Comment: tickInterval should be used when your data isn't returning xAxis values. Since you have timestamps associated with your data, I assumed you wanted to use them. You also need to be absolutely certain that the intervals match the data being returned, or else it throws everything off. In this case, since you have the data, I would use the formatter.

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way to do is using "minTickInterval"

```
xAxis: {
       minTickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
}
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.minTickInterval

Comment: You need to add `ordinal: false`

Comment: For me, this solution is more accurate. Thanks!